# SwiftUI animate transition between 2 separated views

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I have no idea why I animated transition is not working in my case. I have a login view and a main view, and when i press one button i want to make a smooth transition to the other view. Here is the code that I use.

**What am I missing here?**

Thank you a lot!

```
import SwiftUI

class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var loginScreen: Bool
    
    init(loginScreen: Bool) {
        self.loginScreen = loginScreen
    }
}

@main
struct Test: App {
    @StateObject var appState: AppState = AppState(loginScreen: true)
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if appState.loginScreen {
                LoginView()
                    .environmentObject(appState)
            } else {
                MainView()
                    .environmentObject(appState)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Login View:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoginView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                LogInButton().environmentObject(appState)
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let appState = AppState(loginScreen: true)
        LoginView().environmentObject(appState)
    }
}
```

And this is my button **login view**:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LogInButton: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            appState.loginScreen.toggle()
        }) {
            HStack {
                Text("Log In")  
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LogInButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let appState = AppState(loginScreen: true)
        LogInButton().environmentObject(appState)
    }
}
```

And the **Main view**:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Button("Go to login") {
                appState.loginScreen.toggle()
            }
            .font(.title)
        }
    }
}

struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainView()
    }
}
```

Comment: try using `NavigationStack` instead, that will give you a `smooth` animated transition. See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mainly, there’s no animation because you’re not specifying there to be. When you hit a button that toggles the app state’s boolean value, that triggers SwiftUI to rebuild its idea of the view layout, and it does so as quickly as possible.

One way of controlling how your change animates would be to add transition modifiers to the conditional calls to `LoginView` and `MainView`. To make this easier, I’d move that conditional outside the `Scene` declaration:

```
@main
struct LoginAnimationApp: App {
    // this doesn’t need to be a `StateObject` as this struct doesn’t
    // change whenever `appState` changes
    var appState: AppState = AppState(loginScreen: true)

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(appState)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if appState.loginScreen {
                LoginView()
                    .transition(.opacity)
            } else {
                MainView()
                    .transition(.slide)
            }
        }
        // this modifier determines the timing curve of the transitions
        .animation(.default, value: appState.loginScreen)
    }
}
```

(A quick note: if you declare an `.environmentObject` at the top of your hierarchy, you generally don’t need to redeclare it further down the view tree; SwiftUI automatically passes on environment variables for you. You only opt in to `@EnvironmentObject` in views that need to change in response to the object’s changes).

---

Another option is to make your login screen a `fullScreenCover`, which will automatically animate in to cover any other view, and which is managed by a binding to a Boolean:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState

    var body: some View {
        MainView()
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $appState.loginScreen) {
            LoginView()
        }
    }
}
```

You can dismiss the login view by changing the value of `appState.loginScreen` to false (as your code currently does).

This is cleaner, and you’re leaning on SwiftUI basics that are pretty robust. You don’t have any real flexibility on how animations are presented, though: the login screen will always animate in from the bottom edge. But that’s a familiar style for iOS users so that’s probably okay.